# ¿Por qué sale este mensaje "No se encuentra el archivo ISAM instalable"?

Tags: c#

Alguien que me diga en que me estoy equivocando, tengo el codigo siguiente, en el cual hago una consulta de una hoja de excel:

```
 OpenFileDialog openExcel = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openExcel.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            label2.Text = openExcel.FileName;
            try
            {
                String con = string.Format("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = '" + openExcel.FileName + @"'; Extend Properties = 'Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR = NO' ");
                OleDbConnection conec = default(OleDbConnection);
                conec = new OleDbConnection(con);
                conec.Open();

                OleDbCommand cmd = default(OleDbCommand);
                cmd = new OleDbCommand("select PROGRAMA, LOTE, PEDIDO, LINEA, MODELO, COMB, NUM, FEC ENTREGA, CLIENTE, CANTIDAD, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, N9, N95, N10, N105 from [Hoja1$]", conec);

                OleDbDataAdapter adap = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                adap.SelectCommand = cmd;

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                adap.Fill(ds);
                dgvExcel.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

                conec.Close();

                //OleDbConnection cone = new OleDbConnection(con);

                //OleDbCommand cmd = cone.CreateCommand();
                //cmd.CommandText = "select PROGRAMA, LOTE, PEDIDO, LINEA, MODELO, COMB, NUM, FEC ENTREGA, CLIENTE, CANTIDAD, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, N9, N95, N10, N105 from [Hoja1$]";
                //OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                //DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                //da.Fill(dt);
                //dgvExcel.DataSource = dt;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No se selecciono ningun archivo.");
        }
```

Pero cuando lo ejecuto me manda el siguiente mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pensando que era algo mal de mi programación la cambie pero me siguio saliendo el mismo mensaje, tambien ya reinstale los drivers de office y me sigue saliendo el mismo mensaje.

Comment: Es un problema con los drivers de conexion a la DB (en este caso excel), fijate de buscar que los drivers sean correctos para ese tipo de archivo que queres abrir

Comment: Pero se me hace raro que pase eso, quiero decir, tengo otra forma de mostrarlo en el datagrid, pero ese es solamente seleccionando el archivo, y me muestra los datos sin ningun problema, pero cuando lo hago de esta forma, en la que hago una consulta como en sql es cuando me manda este error

Comment: a que te referis con otra forma? el error en que linea te lo da?

Comment: si solo se selecciona el archivo excel, hago una clase para poner los nombres de las columnas o era algo parecido, y despues hago un  metodo con un forear para recorrer el documento, y me muestra sin ningun problema los datos

Comment: Claro, pero ahi no lo estas abriendo usando un driver de conexion a base de datos. son dos cosas distintas